# sending jquery generated form to php

Tags: php, jquery

I the below script does not work. I am trying to pass values generated using a jquery function to php. when I run this code it. The form slides to the right, but no values are encoded. I am thinking I am doing something simple wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Target Example</title>
    <?php
   $x = $_POST['total'];
   
   echo $x;
   
   ?>
   
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     function compute() {
          var a = $('#a').val();
          var b = $('#b').val();
          var total = a * b;
          $('#total').val(total);
        }

        $('#a, #b').change(compute);
  
   });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
   <div data-role="page" id="irr">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Calculation</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="a">Diameter:</label>
          <input type="number" name="a" id="a" value=""  />
          <label for="b">Diver:</label>
          <input type="number" name="b" id="b" value=""  />
          <label for="total">Result:</label>
          <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value=""  />
          <input type="submit">
        </div>
        What did we do here?
      </div>
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i ask why you use jquery in version 1.6.x? this has a lot of security leaks. 1.12.x is also ie8 compatible. your libraries are definitly outdated. but thats not the problem

Comment: I tried it, and it worked after changing the jquery library to 2.2.1

Comment: Have you thrown in any `alert` statements? A good trouble shooting technique is to put something like `alert(2)` or some number every few lines to see at what point it fails. There’s nothing wrong with your code, although jQuery is _really over the top_ for such a simple task. I can give you a non-jQuery version which will work. Also, your code isn’t optimal, since it spends a lot of time looking for things.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action was not set correctly. Use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead. Also, I used the short hand echo feature in case you are wondering. Hopefully that fixes it for you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Target Example</title>
        <?php
          $x = $_POST['total'];

          echo $x;

          ?>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            function compute() {
              var a = $('#a').val();
              var b = $('#b').val();
              var total = a * b;
              $('#total').val(total);
            }

            $('#a, #b').change(compute);

          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form action="<?=($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])?>" method="post">
        <div data-role="page" id="irr">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Calculation</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              <label for="a">Diameter:</label>
              <input type="number" name="a" id="a" value=""  />
              <label for="b">Diver:</label>
              <input type="number" name="b" id="b" value=""  />
              <label for="total">Result:</label>
              <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value=""  />
              <input type="submit">
            </div>
            What did we do here?
          </div>
         </div>
          </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you do have to actually run this on a web server running PHP to get your result to echo out onto the page!